# Attempting to convert mysql list to python list but it's cutting variables out

Tags: python, mysql

Good Afternoon,

I'm currently attempting to turn my mysql fetchall list into a python list through the following code below.

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM programs")
avail_programs = [item[0] for item in mycursor.fetchall()]
```

and the output is:

```
['Program1', 'Basics']
```

when it should be:

```
[('Program1', '255'), ('Basics', '1')]
```

This is because each program has an identifier attached to it in the mysql database.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: item[0] could refer to the first field in row, maybe you just need to remove [0] from second line in your scrpt.

Comment: There's the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: you could also do `avail_programs = [(item[0], item[1]) for item in mycursor.fetchall()]` then you would get a tuple

Comment: @mama That looks a lot like an answer, so you might want to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do `avail_programs = [(item[0], item[1]) for item in mycursor.fetchall()]` then you would get a tuple

Answer (score 1):

`mycursor.fetchall` already returns list of tuples so you can just do

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM programs")
avail_programs = mycursor.fetchall()
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html